# How can use different language for bootstrap datepicker at toValue/toDisplay?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I know that can change the global one:

```
language: tr
```

But how can I show "tr" to user but leave "en" at value ?

Answer (score 0):

So, my solution was to create an extra input for UI and use moment.js library to display in right language.

```
var end_date_picker = $('#end_date_ui').datepicker({
    language: '{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}',

    format: {
      toDisplay: function (date, format, language) {
           var d = new Date(date);
           $('#end_date').val(moment(d).locale('en').format('MMMM DD, YYYY'))
           return moment(d).locale('{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}').format('MMMM DD, YYYY')
     },
     toValue: function (date, format, language) {
         var d = new Date(date);
         return moment(d).locale('en').format('MMMM DD, YYYY')
     }
    },
 });
```